# How to calculate geodesic sphere vertex coordinates?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

For a 3D graphics application to draw a sphere, I usually combine it from a triangle strips, like so:

[image]

It's extremely easy to generate, using sin/cos with polar coordinates to generate vertices. As well as to texture it. Since you're using pair of polar coordinates - you may naturally map them to points of 2d image. But here goes the problem - If you increase "level of details", by increasing triangle count to make it look nice at closer distances - you'll get triangles at the poles almost degenerated to lines. There are excessively many of them and want to get rid. So I've heard of [geodesic spheres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_geodesic_polyhedra_and_Goldberg_polyhedra#Tetrahedral):

[image]

But I totally miss idea for a vertex and texture coordinate generation - Like How to generate i-th vertex, or i-th face? I mean how would you naturally enumerate them? (You'll have to, since computer memory is always one-dimensional)

So you got a such a mesh of $N$ triangular faces, and for each $i$ from $0$ to $N$, representing single triangle, you will have 3 vertices $(x_1(i),y_1(i),z_1(i)), (x_2(i),y_2(i),z_2(i)), (x_3(i),y_3(i),z_3(i))$
If you have these formulas you may construct it very easily, as you got all vertex coordinatex. What these formulas could look like?

And how would you even may wrap rectangular texture onto that shape? Like for each $i$ how can I find correcponding $x$ and $y$ on a 2D texture image?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17705621/algorithm-for-a-geodesic-sphere

Comment: http://www.dirkbertels.net/computing/pentaDome_files/pentaDome_070206.pdf

Comment: @Aretino Thanks, I would research pdf, that may help. Although there are many ready examples, they all are kind of recursive, with subdivisions, and dont cover texturing question. Probably I may try to [wrap cube onto a sphere](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/43741/how-do-you-turn-a-cube-into-a-sphere), and use 6 textures for all sides..

Comment: Also found [this guide](http://blog.andreaskahler.com/2009/06/creating-icosphere-mesh-in-code.html), but it also dont cover texture mapping question =(

Comment: If you need uv-map for geodesic sphere, you can take a net of icosahedron as its uv map and subdivide uv coordinates of icosahedron along with its normal coordinates while you constructing the coordinates of geodesic sphere. Thus, in the end for each vertex/face you will have both 3d coordinates and uv coordinates

Comment: @VasilyMitch but what is *" a net of icosahedron as its uv map"*? lets say, we have 1024*2048 pixel texture. choose any vertex from ico, lets call it vtx0. how to map texture coords to it? what is vtx1? vtx2? vtx3?.. how to map to them? for now lets dismiss any ico subdivision.. how to texture ico itself?

Comment: How do you texture any mesh? You map every poly of a mesh onto uv-map. You can do it triangle by triangle, you can take a [net](https://p7.hiclipart.com/preview/516/979/785/regular-icosahedron-schlegel-diagram-polyhedron-face-face.jpg), you can go for more [complicated solutions](https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/632975-texturing-a-procedural-icosahedron/).